# jQuery TableSorter not sorting after <td> update database update using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am implementing a rating system, where users can rank up/down entries. Each entry has a rank, initially rank is 0. I have this information stored in a database and then I print this table on a page and I use the jQuery tablesorter class, so all entries are sorted by rank.

When a user ranks up/down  an entry I update the rank in the database and then I display the updated rank using ajax. Each entry has a up and down button.

I have the tablesorter initialized:

```
$(function() {
    $('#list_sort').tablesorter({ 
        sortList: [[0,0]],     // allow sorting on the ranking column only

        headers: {
            1: {
                sorter: false 
            }, 
            2: { 
                sorter: false 
            }, 
            3: { 
                sorter: false 
            }
        }
    })
});
```

The up and down button has a onClick event and that calls a function which updates the database, and then using ajax the ranking  is updated but I want to sort it after it is updated.

I tried several methods including:

```
$('#list_sort').trigger("update");
```

and

```
lastSortList = $("#list_sort")[0].config.sortList;
$("#list_sort").trigger("#list_sort", [lastSortList]);
$('#list_sort').tablesorter();
```

but nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution of this but I don't think this is a good solution. I used 
setTimeout function after the user ranks and the database is updated and it works.

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $('#list_sort').tablesorter({ 
        sortList: [[0,1]],

        headers: {
            1: {
                sorter: false 
            }, 
            2: { 
                sorter: false 
            }, 
            3: { 
                sorter: false 
            }
        }
    })
    }, 50);
```